# ios review: binary include the framework I didn't install

Tags: ios, react-native

I just submit my app to apple review , already remove all apple pay code but ios review tell me
binary includes passkit framework
should I only explain on the review notes or other checking
below content was ios review
We're looking forward to completing our review of your app, but we need more information to continue. Specifically, we noticed that your binary includes the PassKit framework for implementing Apple Pay, but we were unable to verify any integration of Apple Pay within your app.

If your app does not include any Apple Pay functionality, please indicate this information in the Review Notes section for each version of your app in App Store Connect when submitting for review.

Comment: Just do what they ask. If you don’t provide Apple pay just state that in the review notes. If you do, then tell them where they can find the functionality in the review notes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because App Store review is off topic

Comment: even you remove the code ,but the project.pbxbroj still have some reference here ,and you need to remove those reference on your project  , not all about ios review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you have upload app make sure remove capability of apple pay from project. It may be help you to successfully release application.

Please find below image for your reference.
[image]

Comment: I removed the compile resource file and disable the capability ,seems ok